# EvolutionsComponents in compile-time dependency injection play project

Tags: scala, playframework-2.5, playframework-evolutions

Im trying to understand how to run evolutions using compile-time DI.

```
import play.api.ApplicationLoader.Context
import play.api.cache.EhCacheComponents
import play.api.mvc.EssentialFilter
import play.api.routing.Router
import play.api._
import play.api.db.evolutions.{ DynamicEvolutions, EvolutionsComponents}
import play.filters.gzip.GzipFilter
import router.Routes

class AppLoader extends ApplicationLoader  {
  override def load(context: Context): Application = {
    LoggerConfigurator(context.environment.classLoader).foreach(_.configure(context.environment))
    new AppComponents(context).application
  }


}

class AppComponents(context: Context) extends BuiltInComponentsFromContext(context) with EhCacheComponents with EvolutionsComponents {

  lazy val applicationController = new controllers.Application(defaultCacheApi)
  lazy val usersController = new controllers.Users(defaultCacheApi)
  lazy val assets = new controllers.Assets(httpErrorHandler)

  applicationEvolutions

  // Routes is a generated class
  override def router: Router = new Routes(httpErrorHandler, applicationController, usersController, assets)

  val gzipFilter = new GzipFilter(shouldGzip =
    (request, response) => {
      val contentType = response.header.headers.get("Content-Type")
      contentType.exists(_.startsWith("text/html")) || request.path.endsWith("jsroutes.js")
    })

  override lazy val httpFilters: Seq[EssentialFilter] = Seq(gzipFilter)


}
```

But I keep getting error 
Error:(19, 7) class AppComponents needs to be abstract, since method dbApi in trait EvolutionsComponents of type => play.api.db.DBApi is not defined
class AppComponents(context: Context) extends BuiltInComponentsFromContext(context) with EhCacheComponents with EvolutionsComponents

I'am newbie in Scala.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`dbApi` comes from the `DBComponents` trait, so your `AppComponents` class needs to also extend `DBComponents`. You'll also need to extend `HikariCPComponents` for the connection pool.

```
class AppComponents(context: Context) extends BuiltInComponentsFromContext(context)
  with EhCacheComponents
  with EvolutionsComponents
  with DBComponents
  with HikariCPComponents {
```

Be sure to add the `evolutions` and `jdbc` dependencies to your `build.sbt` file.

Comment: This worked: class AppComponents(context: Context) extends BuiltInComponentsFromContext(context) with EhCacheComponents with EvolutionsComponents with DBComponents with HikariCPComponents, but how colud I get it my self? For example this HikariCPComponents is also needed ?

Comment: What do you mean by "get it my self"? What do you want to get? Also, what library are you using for JDBC access? Slick?

Comment: I tried to reverse-engineere dependancy to get to this conclusion myself.  I was looking at EvolutionsModule.scala - trait EvolutionsComponents. But I cloudnt connect EvolutionsComponents and DBComponents  ( play-jdbc-api_2.11-2.5.6.jar). And again how could I know that I need include libraryDependencies ( jdbc) wich brings play-jdbc_2.11-2.5.6.jar - in wich there is this HikariCPComponents that also need to be implemented.
Cloude I get the same coclusion just looking at code somehow, or evolution documentation ? In Play documentation they say nothing about this.

Comment: Agreed, the Play documentation could be much better. I'm glad you figured it out! Typically, my strategy for these kind of issues is to look at code examples by open source projects..

Answer (score 0):

I needed to extend all of this. More reading Cake Pattern [Play documentation](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.5.x/ScalaCompileTimeDependencyInjection#Compile-Time-Dependency-Injection)

```
class AppComponents(context: Context) extends BuiltInComponentsFromContext(context) with EhCacheComponents with EvolutionsComponents with DBComponents with HikariCPComponents{
```

and add jdbc suport inside build.sbt

```
libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
 filters,
 evolutions,
 jdbc,
 cache,
```

....